# Creating a loop, which picks up where the previous stopped

Tags: r, list, for-loop

The reason for this question, is that I need to download data for which there is a daily download limit. I am trying to write a loop that picks up with downloading where it left off (for the next day).

I created the following example, in which I replaced the download function with a simple index (`item_list[i+amount_done]`):

```
# data = a list, to be filled with all the downloads
data = list()

# Yesterday, I did one list item, so the amount done is 1
data[[1]] <- "1"
amount_done <- length(data)

# The list of items that need to be downloaded
item_list <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")

# The loop I created to pick up where it stopped
for (i in (1+amount_done):length(item_list)){
  data[[i+amount_done]] <- item_list[i+amount_done] # This is where the download function would be using the index as used in this example.
  print(data[[i+amount_done]])
}
```

Somehow, this is the outcome:

[image]

The desired result is simply

```
data[[1]] 
"1"
data[[2]] 
"2"
data[[3]] 
"3"
data[[4]] 
"4"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just create a new list each day, and iterate over the whole list? That way you don’t have to bother with indices, you can iterate directly over items, making the code much simpler.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why iterate over whole list everyday? Wouldn't that be wasting lot of resources where it is not needed? Some part of the list is already downloaded yesterday and we need to start downloading from the remaining part today.

Comment: @RonakShah That’s why I said “create a new list each day”. The lists can obviously be merged after processing if that’s required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is the correct index that you want to use in the loop.

```
data = list()

# Yesterday, I did one list item, so the amount done is 1
data[[1]] <- "1"
amount_done <- length(data)

# The list of items that need to be downloaded
item_list <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")

# The loop I created to pick up where it stopped
for (i in (1+amount_done):length(item_list)){
  data[[i]] <- item_list[i] 
  print(data[[i]])
}

data

#[[1]]
#[1] "1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2"

#[[3]]
#[1] "3"

#[[4]]
#[1] "4"
```